# Sort the coordinates of points by areas that they occupy (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, python-2.7, math

Suppose we have a particular number of points distributed in the plane at the nodes of a grid having a given step. These points form several continuous regions.

We can tell that points (if there is more than one point) form a continuous region if for each point in region there is another point at a distance less than or equal to `step*sqrt(2)`.

It is necessary to have only a single list (or dictionary) of coordinates and grid step, to distribute the coordinates to new arrays. Each new array should contain coordinates that belong to a particular region.

Below is a picture for clarity. In this case, we have three continuous regions.

[image]

Now I have the following implementation.

```
from itertools import groupby


step = 1
regions = [] # list of lists with points from particular regions
while all_equal(list(points.values())) == False: # while not all points have been explored ("points" is a single dict with coordinates, where keys are numbers of points and values are tuples with coordinates)
    region = [] # create a list for new region
    region.append(points[list(points.keys())[0]]) # add to the new list the first value from "points"
    points[list(points.keys())[0]] = None # "None" means that this point has already been explored
    for point in points:
        for region_point in region:
            if points[point] != None: # if this point has not already been explored
                if distance(points[point], region_point) <= step*2**0.5: # if these points form a continuous segment
                    region.append(points[point])
                    points[point] = None
                    break
    regions.append(region)
    points = {k:v for k,v in points.items() if v != None} # remove all explored points from a single dict

for element in regions:
    print element


def all_equal(array):
    g = groupby(array)
    return next(g, True) and not next(g, False)
```

But this code works incorrectly. Moreover, it is organized in a very suboptimal way. But now I have no idea how it could be realized differently.

An example of input data:

```
    points = {
        1: (1, 10),
        2: (1, 8),
        3: (2, 9),
        4: (2, 6),
        5: (3, 8),
        6: (3, 7),
        7: (3, 6),
        8: (6, 7),
        9: (7, 8),
        10: (7, 7),
        11: (8, 7),
        12: (8, 6),
        13: (10, 5),
        14: (11, 6),
        15: (12, 6),
        16: (12, 5),
        17: (13, 6),
        18: (13, 5)
    }
```

Expected result:

```
[(1, 10), (1, 8), (2, 9), (2, 6), (3, 8), (3, 7), (3, 6)]
[(6, 7), (7, 8), (7, 7), (8, 7), (8, 6)]
[(10, 5), (11, 6), (12, 6), (12, 5), (13, 6), (13, 5)]
```

Current result:

```
[(1, 10), (2, 9), (3, 8), (3, 7), (3, 6)]
[(1, 8)]
[(2, 6)]
[(6, 7), (7, 8), (7, 7), (8, 7), (8, 6)]
[(10, 5), (11, 6), (12, 6), (12, 5), (13, 6), (13, 5)]
```

Please use Python 2 to solve this problem (or Python 3 without libraries that are missing in Python 2).

Comment: You want code that works with both Python 3 and Python 2? Python 2 has been abandoned for several years, and should not be used. I don't think that requirement has any validity.

Comment: It is unclear what the precise definition is for points to belong to the same region. What makes a point belong to one specific region, and not another? In the example image, why are there three regions?

Comment: Also consider using scikit-learn with [clustering methods](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering).

Comment: Your code uses `all_equal`, but that is not defined. It may seems obvious (as to what it does), but it could be a function with a bug, causing the code not to work, so we'd have to know what that code looks like.

Comment: @9769953 That requirement is mine. You can use Python 3 without libraries that are missing in Python 2. This is because I am writing a calculation data processor for the Abaqus software package, which only supports Python 2.

Comment: @9769953 Sorry, I forgot to include all_equal function. Corrected

Comment: Ok; doesn't it make sense to tag it [python2] then, and restrict the code to Python 2? (In which case something like `list(point.values())` isn't really necessary; just `point.values()` is enough.)

Comment: @9769953 
Yes you are right. Habit from the python 3 :)

Comment: Not using Python 3 libraries does not mean code will work in Python 2. The language has changed significantly, even when it comes to base language features. If you are forced to work with Python 2, then stick with it, instead of trying to eat cake and have cake.

Comment: @matszwecja It doesn't matter what version of python you use in your version. If it is python 3, I can easily translate the code to python 2 (but, again, please don't use libraries missing in python 2). The algorithm itself is important.

Comment: You keep resetting `regions` to an empty list in your while loop; is that correct?

Comment: @9769953 Yes, it's correct, because this is `region`, not `regions`, On each iteration of while loop we collect points of a new region in `region` variable and in the end of iteration add this variable in `regions`. On the new iteration we assign an empty list to `region` because we start to explore new region.

Comment: Ok, I missed the `regions.append(region)` at the bottom.

Comment: Do you have an example of input (and output) for which the code doesn't not work correctly? And the expected output.

Comment: @9769953 yes, wait a little please

Comment: Actually, I'd argue the region part it's not correct: a point P that initially didn't belong to a certain region (call it A), could belong to that region A in a second iteration of the while loop, because later points that were added to region A might be close enough to P to include it in the region. But when going a second time through the while loop, region A is not used.

Comment: I guess a one-dimensional example of the my comment above would be points 1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 6, and inclusion distance of <= 1. You start of with a region of 1, add 2, skip 5, add 3, add 4, then skip 6. Then you start a *new* region with 5, and add 6 to it. You end up with regions (1, 2, 3, 4) and (5, 6), while in fact it is one big region.

Comment: @9769953 Yes, you're right. And that's why I wrote in my question that my algorithm works incorrect. Unfortunately, now I have no idea how to solve this problem in a correct way.
By the way, I added an example of input data in question.

Comment: All you seem to have given us is a sample input, sample output and basically no logic behind how that sample input gets converted to the output, and why the expected output is "correct" compared to the actual output of your program. Please visit the [help] and read [ask]. Your question currently lacks proper details.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thank you very much, I am very familiar with the site rules. The question contains all the necessary information, including a picture from which you can understand the principle by which points are divided into regions.

If you are unable to write something constructive, it is better not to write anything at all.

Comment: You probably need to iterate over existing regions to see if there are any points to be added; and again, and again (i.e., a nested loop). Only when no points can be added to any of the existing regions anymore, you add a new region (with one of the remaining points), then start the loop over all existing regions again.

Comment: I'd: (1) put all points in an "open" set (2) start from any point and add it to the cluster and the cluster's unchecked points set (3) look at whether there is a neighbor in any of the 8 surrounding cells, and if so, remove them from the open set and add them to this cluster and this cluster's unchecked points set (3) repeat  until there is nothing in the open set

Comment: @AlexanderFedorov maybe you miss the point that what might be obvious to you as the asker might not be so obvious to others. That image doesn't really help us understand your problem other than that there's some arbitrary criteria according to which points are in regions. What is this criteria? Other than this you also mention that you need to "_distribute the coordinates to new arrays_" again what's the criteria for this distribution?

Comment: I am taking a guess here, points Pa and Pb can be said to be connected if the [Chebyshev distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance) between the two points is equal to `step` and points P1 to Pn are in a region if all of these points are connected to each other directly or indirectly? If this is the case is this information not crucial to anyone answering your question? How else would we understand what the vague "_having a given step_" means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick (tried on Python 2.7.18, works fine, and just so happens to be artisanal code that works on Python 3.11 too).

The idea is that we do a sort of "flood-fill" or walk across the cells.

The output is

```
[(1, 10), (1, 8), (2, 9), (2, 6), (3, 8), (3, 7), (3, 6)]
[(6, 7), (7, 8), (7, 7), (8, 7), (8, 6)]
[(10, 5), (11, 6), (12, 6), (12, 5), (13, 6), (13, 5)]
```

as expected.

```
def get_neighbors(point_id_to_coords, open_point_ids, point_id):
    x, y = point_id_to_coords[point_id]
    for neighbor in open_point_ids:
        nx, ny = point_id_to_coords[neighbor]
        if abs(x - nx) <= 1 and abs(y - ny) <= 1:
            yield neighbor


def cluster_points(point_id_to_coords):
    # Create a set of all point IDs that haven't been visited yet
    open_point_ids = set(point_id_to_coords)

    # While there are unclustered points, choose a random point
    while open_point_ids:
        start = open_point_ids.pop()

        # Initialize a new cluster, and its open points with only the start point
        cluster = {start}
        cluster_open = {start}

        # While there are still points to be examined for this cluster, choose a random point
        while cluster_open:
            point = cluster_open.pop()
            neighbor_ids = set(get_neighbors(point_id_to_coords, open_point_ids, point))
            # For each neighboring point, add it to the cluster and remove it from the unvisited sets
            for neighbor in neighbor_ids:
                cluster.add(neighbor)
                cluster_open.add(neighbor)
                open_point_ids.remove(neighbor)

        yield cluster


points = {
    1: (1, 10),
    2: (1, 8),
    3: (2, 9),
    4: (2, 6),
    5: (3, 8),
    6: (3, 7),
    7: (3, 6),
    8: (6, 7),
    9: (7, 8),
    10: (7, 7),
    11: (8, 7),
    12: (8, 6),
    13: (10, 5),
    14: (11, 6),
    15: (12, 6),
    16: (12, 5),
    17: (13, 6),
    18: (13, 5),
}

for cluster in cluster_points(points):
    print([points[pid] for pid in cluster])
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is a good candidate for [Disjoint sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure), which will still be efficient on larger datasets.

Here is an implementation (a.k.a. Union-Find):

```
# Generic DisjointSet
class DisjointSet:
    def __init__(self, keys):
        self.parent = { key: key for key in keys }
        self.rank = { key: 0 for key in keys }
     
    def find(self, a):
        if self.parent[a] != a:
            self.parent[a] = self.find(self.parent[a])
        return self.parent[a]
    
    def union(self, a, b):
        a = self.find(a)
        b = self.find(b)
        if a != b:
            if self.rank[a] < self.rank[b]:
                a, b = b, a
            self.parent[b] = a
            if self.rank[a] == self.rank[b]:
                self.rank[a] += 1

    def sets(self):
        result = {}
        for key in self.parent:
            root = self.find(key)
            if root not in result:
                result[root] = []
            result[root].append(key)
        return list(result.values())


# Function specific for your problem:
def components(points):
    pointset = set(points)
    dset = DisjointSet(points)
    
    # check for each neighbor point of each member whether it is in the collection
    for point in points:
        x, y = point
        for dx in range(-1, 2):
            for dy in range(-1, 2):
                if (dx or dy) and (x + dx, y + dy) in pointset:
                    # if so, put both node and neighbor in the same set
                    dset.union(point, (x + dx, y + dy))
    
    return dset.sets()

# Example run
points = {
    1: (1, 10),
    2: (1, 8),
    3: (2, 9),
    4: (2, 6),
    5: (3, 8),
    6: (3, 7),
    7: (3, 6),
    8: (6, 7),
    9: (7, 8),
    10: (7, 7),
    11: (8, 7),
    12: (8, 6),
    13: (10, 5),
    14: (11, 6),
    15: (12, 6),
    16: (12, 5),
    17: (13, 6),
    18: (13, 5)
}
print(components(points.values()))
```